# How to design the HTML email body using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is it possible to create an HTML email body by means of Thymeleaf without using the MVC route?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You notice that your question is downvoted. That is because most of us are generally wondering what your question is. Could you please expand your question a bit and clearly include what your problem is. Example code is always a good start. Have a look at [ask] and take the [tour]. You can [edit] your question by clicking edit below your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you find an example how you can achieve this.

```
@Bean
public ITemplateEngine htmlTemplateEngine() {
SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
templateResolver.setPrefix("/");
templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
return templateEngine;
}
```

next create a context as shown below

```
final Context ctx = new Context();
```

insert the string/object in to context.

```
String inLineMessage = "String/Object to insert in HTML";
ctx.setVariable("inLineMessage ", commitAllocationResponse);
```

Call the method

```
String html = htmlTemplateEngine.process("//templates//EmailTemplate.html", ctx);
```

inbuild functions in thymeleaf

```
check the size of list
th:if="${#lists.size(exampleList)} &gt; 0">
//String equals check
th:if="${megaDetails.megaType } eq 'SFFIXMEGA' or ${megaDetails.megaType } eq 
     'MFFIXMEGA' "
Aggregate the varible in list
#aggregates.sum(commitAllocationResponse.allocatedMegas.![feeDollars])
```

Comment: I'm puzzled, did you just answer your own question? Or is this part of the question?

Comment: I answered my own question. if any body needs help they can use this code as example